# Sub-menu's border is not left aligned with parent's?

Tags: html, css

Why the sub-menu's border is not left aligned with its parent?

Here is the [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ipkiss/vs9asd5r/4/)

HTML

```
<nav id="su-top-header">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="su-dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#">Question &#9662;</a>
                  <ul class="su-dropdown-content">
                      <li><a href="/">About us</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/">About our product</a></li>
                      <li><a href="/">About our services</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Application</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
```

CSS

```
#su-top-header {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#su-top-header ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: inside none;
}

#su-top-header > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#su-top-header ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.su-dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.su-dropdown-menu:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

#su-top-header .su-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0;
}

.su-dropdown-content li{
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}

.su-dropdown-content li:hover{
    background-color: bisque;
}

.su-dropdown-content li a{
    display: block;   
}

#su-top-header .su-dropdown-menu:hover .su-dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

I saw many samples and all sub-menus are `left aligned` with their parents.
Something's wrong with my code?

Comment: Kindly add the code in the question, please.

Comment: The border is what is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you have border on a parent and one of its children, and as the parents border is outside the content area, the child's border will not align being inside the content area.

Put the border on the anchor, see below sample, or use a pseudo on your parent, which shows a border on hover.

```css
#su-top-header {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#su-top-header ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: inside none;
}

#su-top-header > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#su-top-header ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.su-dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
}

.su-dropdown-menu > a {
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.su-dropdown-menu:hover > a {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

#su-top-header .su-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0;
}

.su-dropdown-content li{
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}

.su-dropdown-content li:hover{
    background-color: bisque;
}

.su-dropdown-content li a{
    display: block;   
}

#su-top-header .su-dropdown-menu:hover .su-dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="su-top-header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="su-dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#">Question &#9662;</a>
      <ul class="su-dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="/">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">About our product</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">About our services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Application</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to sunil.. You can use `-0.6px` rather then `-1px` for `#su-top-header .su-dropdown-content` and you will get desired output in any screen.

```
#su-top-header .su-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -0.6px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vs9asd5r/7/)

Comment: But how? What's the reason behind it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is causing because of border of su-dropdown-menu. So left will remove the issue.

Comment: No, but why `0.6` and not `1`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar well i came to know after inspecting that border of menu is giving issue. So i tried to change the value and at fix value i got the answer so i posted. Sorry but i don't have FULL KNOWLEDGE but i think i helped op..isnt it enough also i did not just post the code but tell him what i change. I don't know what you are looking for.